# Call sibling element in javascript function array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, requirejs

im currently developing with requirejs and have a module wich returns two functions in an assoziative array, now I want to call the first function from the second one, I tried this.foo(), but it didn't work.
Is there a way to call a sibling element in a assoziative array, or perhaps require the module in itself?

example:

```
define[],function(){
  return {
    foo: function() { echo("foo");},
    bar: function() { this.foo();}
  }
}
```

Comment: Depends on how you're calling it exactly. Show that too.

Comment: The code in the question won't execute, due to syntax errors. To get good and relevant answers it helps to post code that is free syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing exactly how you're trying to call `bar` it's hard to know exactly what's going wrong. That said, this should work for you, assuming the problem is that `this` isn't referring to the right thing when calling `bar()`:

```
define[], function(){
  var baz = {
    foo: function() { echo("foo");},
    bar: function() { baz.foo();}
  };

  return baz;
}
```

Since it basically "statically" does the same thing as [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: That worked, it seems, if I return the array anonymously like in my example `this` referes to Window, while defining it as a variable and calling the function on the Variable works.

Comment: It's not about how you _return_ the object (it's an object, not an array) but how it's later used.